# Linux (CentOS 6.6) Create User Restrict FTP/SSH Access & Only Allow Certain Set Of Commands

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, user

I have a VPS server that runs a script all day that is used for validating clients using our software. Problem is that sometimes this script will crash and I need to restart it. I know someone who I want to let restart the script when I am not around the problem with that Is that I do not want to allow him to access the VPS via FTP/SSH, and I want to restrict his user to a certain set of commands.

for example only these commands (just to list a few)

```
service mysqld start
screen -ls
```

Answer (score 0):

You can allow him to connect to the your server via SSH, as a regular user and then give him sudo rights strictly for the action you want him to perform.

You should add a new group for that (let's name it services for now):

```
sudo addgroup services
```

Add your guy's user to that group:

```
sudo adduser your_guy_user services
```

Edit /etc/sudoers.d/services and add an entry for the services group:

```
%services ALL=(ALL) /usr/sbin/service
%services ALL=(ALL) /usr/bin/service mysqld *
%services ALL=(ALL) /path-to/screen
```

Save the file, ask your guy to login via ssh and try to restart the mysql service.

If you want to restrict the commands he can use then you have to change the permissions for those commands:

**/bin/ping** - by default has **755** permissions (owner has **rwx**, group has **rx**, other has **rx**) so the command can be executed by everyone. If you do not want the ping command to be available for your guy, then do a `chmod 750 /bin/ping`. This way only the root user and the group root will have execution rights for that command. This is merely an example, you can extrapolate from here.

So in the end the user has to be able to login to your server via SSH to restart that service. Of course, that can be achieved in other different ways like having a python script that acts as a webserver so the user connect's there and logs in with an username and a password and issue the restart command (the script can be in python, perl, php) but that requires coding and actually creating the script.

So I would go with the first option.